# How do you change the default calculated column formula in an Excel list table?

Tags: excel, calculated-columns

I have a list with a column that did a lookup to another sheet in the workbook. The original formula looked like this: =VLOOKUP([@[Last Name]]&" "&[@[First Initial]],LookupLastF,9,FALSE).

Later the lookup column was moved, so I had to change the formula to lookup column 10 instead of 9: =VLOOKUP([@[Last Name]]&" "&[@[First Initial]],LookupLastF,10,FALSE). I had to manually copy the formula through the column, because there were exceptions -- i.e. some items overwrote the formula with manually entered values.

The problem is every time a new row is inserted into the table, the old formula is copied to the  row instead of the corrected formula. So a default based on the original formula must still exist somewhere.  How do I change it to the new formula?

Comment: You have to delete the content of the whole column and then apply a new formula. Mixing formula and static values within one column is not a good idea. Use three columns instead: calculated value, manual value, result value (where a formula shows the manual value if exists and if not the calculated value)

Comment: Thank you.. Deleting the column and inserting a new one with the new formula did the trick.  I have one more question: -- how do I mark your response as the answer to the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - I added the comment as answer :-) Btw - it's sufficient to delete the content of the column - it's not necessary to delete the whole column

Comment: I tried deleting the contents of the column originally (after copying the manually overridden values to another column), so I could start fresh. But when I inserted a new row -- even when the complete column was empty -- the old formula was inserted.  That's when I posted this question.  So, in my case at least, I did need to delete the whole column and replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delete **the content of the whole column** and then (re-)apply the formula.

Mixing formula and static values within one column isn't a good idea.

Use three columns instead: calculated value, manual value, result value (where a formula shows the manual value if exists and if not the calculated value)